# Placing a conditional return inside a bash function

Tags: bash, if-statement

I know that its possible to have a `return` within an `if [ ]` statement. However, the return (I think) must be an integer, and I need to return a string. For example:

```
#Function returns a date value formatted %Y-%m-%d
function chartStartsAt () {

    CHART_START=`jq 'map(.closedDate | values) | min' < output/json/FullIssueList.json`;
    CHART_START="${CHART_START//\"}"

    #Check if the date is null, if so return todays date -1
    if [ -z CHART_START ]
    then
        echo "date -v-1d +%Y-%m-%d";
    else
        echo "${CHART_START%T*}";
    fi

}
```

Comment: http://m.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Comment: That links goes directly to linuxjournal.com. I figured it out though. Thanks @PaulR

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this does work. I was missing a couple of things. I've listed them below.

1. When null, jq returns the string `"null"`, as a result the if statement should be checking for a string not an actual null value
2. My first echo was incorrect and should have been `echo $(date -v-1d +%Y-%m-%d);`

   ```
   function chartStartsAt () {


     CHART_START=`jq 'map(.closedDate | values) | min' < output/json/FullIssueList.json`;
     #echo "${CHART_START}";

     CHART_START="${CHART_START//\"}"
     #echo "${CHART_START}";

     if [ "$CHART_START" == "null" ]
     then
         echo $(date -v-1d +%Y-%m-%d);
     else
         echo "${CHART_START%T*}";
     fi

   }
   ```